# Thiamin quantity in Kiwi - which source to believe?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

I would like to know what is the Thiamin quantity in Kiwi.

There are two websites:

http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/2300?manu=&fgcd=
which says that there is 0.027mg Thiamin in 100g of Kiwi

http://www.foodcomp.dk/v7/fcdb_details.asp?FoodId=0465
which says there is 0.006mg of Thiamin in 100g Kiwi

So, one website claims the quantity is 4.5 times more than the other.

Which information is more reliable and why?

Is there any obvious reason that I am missing why there is such huge difference? I think the product name and quantity and units agree in both websites, so..?

Comment: Both sources seem reputable, I wouldn't be able to decide witch one is more so. As for the difference - the quantity of any substance produced in plants may vary according to biotic and abiotic factors (amount of rain and sunshine, type of soil etc.), or sort/variety/cultivar. Plants can even absorb thiamine produced by bacteria and fungi from the soil, and store it. I don't know if these factors can account for such a big difference (maybe someone at biology SE would know) but this is the only reason (aside from one of the websites being wrong) that I can think of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not directly relate to health

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about nutrient content and website verification.